# Menu not working how it should?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, menu, navbar

I have created a basic login page. this page will store the username and user ID in cookies. so, The menu at the top of the page, on the right, will check depending if the user has logged in or hasn't logged in yet.

I am going to use an if statement. if the statements result is true it will show the sign in and register button. if it is false it will show the logged in as:, my profile, settings and the log out button.

```
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!--login bit-->
                <!--add if statement, e.g. if condition is logged in then show logged in menu. If not, show buttons-->
                  <?php
                  if (($_COOKIE['userID']) == null){
                      //true
                      //show sign in
                      ?>
                        <li><p><center><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="login.php" role="button">Sign In</a><center></p></li>
                      <?php
                      //show register button
                      ?>
                        <li><p><center><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="register.php" role="button">Register</a><center></p></li>
                      <?php
            } else {
                //false
                //show 'logged in as'
                ?>
                <li><a href="#">Logged in as: <?php echo ($_COOKIE['user']) ?></a></li>
                <?php//show 'my profile'?>
                <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                <?php//show 'settings'.?>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><p><center><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="logout.php" role="button">Sign Out</a><center></p></li>
                    <!--<br/><a href ="login.php">Go back to the login screen.</a>-->

                                <!--logged in menu-->
                    <!--<li><a href="#">User ID: <php echo ($_COOKIE['userID']) ?></a></li>-->
                  </ul>
```

Comment: First check your cookie set or not .
`var_dump($_COOKIE['userID']);`
`var_dump($_COOKIE['user']);`

Comment: @JaydeepMor 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in on line 38

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your full code for better understands.